# Using express-flash, console showing no logs, not even reaching my ejs file to set off the toastr notification

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I've setup express-flash, thought it fit what I needed, and somehow doesnt work.

I've looked at about 5 youtube videos and I just cannot fix it.

Edit: Think it might be something with my configuration or maybe I need to apply the flash to the router rather than app, since I’m using the router instead?

This is my router listening for /profile GET:

```
router.get("/profile", userController.userAuth, (req, res) => {
    // userAuth just returns next with the users data to render
    if (req.user) {
        res.render("profile", {
            message: req.flash("message"),
            status: "loggedIn",
            user: req.user,
            error: false
        });
    } else {
        res.redirect("/404");
    };
});
```

This is my router post listening for /profile POST

```
router.post("/profile", upload.single('sampleFile'), (req, res) => {
    // it does file uploading usually, but commented all out for testing this
    req.flash('message', 'This is a flash test.');
    return res.redirect('/profile');
});
```

This is my .ejs file on the client listening for new messages and displaying them with toastr

```
<% if (message.length > 0) { %>
        <script>
            var message = "<%= message  %>";
            toastr.success(message, "Success", {
                positionClass: 'toast-bottom-left'
            });
        </script>
    <% } %>
```

There's no sort of errors or anything on the console. Not sure what on earth the issue is.. Literally just doesn't work.

Obviously have tried removing the upload.single('sampleFile') just incase:

```
router.post("/profile", upload.single('sampleFile'), (req, res) => {
    // it does file uploading usually, but commented all out for testing this
    req.flash('message', 'This is a flash test.');
    return res.redirect('/profile');
});
```

-- Did nothing

Tried breaking the ejs down super simple to just a paragraph element

```
<p> <%= message  %> </p>
```

-- Did nothing

Comment: Can you explain what the intended behavior is? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: It’s a profile page and it’s just supposed to handle an upload file request for a new profile picture. Took all the logic out though for now. I needed express flash to display notifications when it’s uploaded and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind sharing the rest of the server code? You may be doing this already but are you initializing `express-flash`?

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const flash = require('express-flash');

// initialize express-flash
app.use(flash());

// continue rest of server code
```

Comment: Yeah I've initialized express-flash. Not sure if it's good though. Where can I show my app.js code?